# Compiled opencv3.2.0 on ubuntu16.04 failed

Tags: linux, opencv

I failed to compile opencv3.2.0 on ubuntu 16.04,that is the error:
  Build output check failed:Regex: 'command line option .* is valid for .* but not for C++'
I tried to add -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-5 and -D ENABLE_CXX11=ON but it didn't work...So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: opencv_3.2.0 CMAKE configuring → Default "rules"  (ref. Ubuntu 18.04) : See line 32 .. 67 → https://www.dropbox.com/s/45l523eggkh5n9u/opencv320.rules.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04.6 - amd64 : Build opencv-3.2.0

```
sudo apt build-dep opencv
sudo apt install cmake python3-dev python3-numpy libgl1-mesa-dev libgoogle-glog-dev \  
libgphoto2-dev liblapack-dev libleptonica-dev libprotobuf-dev libraw1394-dev libtbb-dev \ 
libtesseract-dev libv4l-dev maven-repo-helper ocl-icd-opencl-dev protobuf-compiler \ 
python-dev libtiff-dev libswscale-dev python-vtk *gstreamer*-dev linux-libc-dev \ 
libavresample-dev libatlas-cpp-0.6-dev libopenblas-dev doxygen \ 
libinsighttoolkit4-dev liblapacke-dev


tar xvf opencv_3.2.0+dfsg.orig.tar.gz
cd opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/
tar xvf ../opencv_3.2.0+dfsg-6.debian.tar.xz 
mkdir build && cd build/

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
    -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON \
    -DOPENCV_MATHJAX_RELPATH=/usr/share/javascript/mathjax/ \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  \
    -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON    \
    -DWITH_FFMPEG=ON    \
    -DWITH_GSTREAMER=OFF    \
    -DWITH_GTK=ON   \
    -DWITH_JASPER=OFF   \
    -DWITH_JPEG=ON  \
    -DWITH_PNG=ON   \
    -DWITH_TIFF=ON  \
    -DWITH_OPENEXR=ON \
    -DWITH_PVAPI=ON \
    -DWITH_UNICAP=OFF   \
    -DWITH_EIGEN=ON \
    -DWITH_VTK=ON \
    -DWITH_GDAL=ON \
    -DWITH_GDCM=ON \
    -DWITH_XINE=OFF \
    -DWITH_IPP=OFF \
    -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=ON \
    -DWITH_CUDA=OFF \
    -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
    -DWITH_IPP=OFF \
    -DWITH_CAROTENE=OFF \
    -DOPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH="/usr/include/CL/" ../

make              ## no errors
.
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_version
.
[100%] Built target opencv_version
```